# "accept-ranges" header set to "none" instead of "bytes"

Tags: http, nginx, curl, http-accept-header

I was getting following response after making a curl request to an endpoint

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 10:11:39 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 1952
server: nginx
x-powered-by: Express
cache-control: public, max-age=0
last-modified: Tue, 21 May 2019 10:11:37 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block;
accept-ranges: bytes
```

Ultimately, I don't want ***accept-ranges: bytes*** , instead it must be ***"accept-ranges: none"***

I tried following in the nginx configurations

```
 server {
 ..... 
 .....
 .....
       location / {
        ......        
        ......
              max_ranges 0;
              proxy_force_ranges on;
        ......
        }
  }
```

What could be the possible issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried removing "proxy_force_ranges on" ? It enables byte-range support for responses from the proxied server regardless of the “Accept-Ranges” field in these responses.